# Why is my application not using all cores on Mac OS X?

Tags: multithreading, macos, pthreads

I have a simple pthread program that (should) spawn a whole lot of threads that just spin and consume CPU. However, I never see this program taking more than 1 of my 4 cores on my Mac OS X Mavericks notebook.

Theories as to why this is happening:

- Is this the OS that's preventing one process from taking over the machine?
- Is the OS X scheduler very tight about affinity?
- Is this a kernel setting I can tweak some where?
- Is the pthread implementation on OS X hobbled in some way?

I have no idea.

I'm asking because I also have a serious application (written in D) that I'd like to use all CPU for some parallel work, but even the simplest pthread program doesn't go over 1 core.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *waste_time(void* a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    const int threads = 100;
    pthread_t thread[threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, waste_time, NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the printf() call out of the waste_time() loop - it's being called 10000000 times!   Get rid of it entirely or put it outside the loop, just before the return.

The operation of waste_time() is currently dominated by that C lib and, underneath OS I/O, call, which, in order to prevent disastrous multithread access to stdout, has an internal lock.  The lock serialises almost the entire run of your process and so the OS can run it, (mostly) on one core.

Comment: Or, to put it simply, only one thread can output at a time, and only a thread that can output can make forward progress. So there's no way this code can keep more than one core busy.